# grunt-contrib-copy is corrupting binary files

Tags: angularjs, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am using the "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0" and the copied binary files are getting damaged, Please look at my grunt configuration and help me on this.

```
copy: {
    options: {
        // exclude binary format from the processContent function
        processContentExclude: [
            '**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd,ttf,otf,woff,svg}'
        ]
    },
    main: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= options.src %>',
            src: ['**/*.json', '**/*.htm*', '**/*.png'],
            dest: '<%= options.targets.dist %>'
        },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= options.resources %>',
                src: ['**/*.png'],
                dest: '<%= options.targets.dist %>',
                options: {
                    options: {
                        processContentExclude: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd}']
                    }
                }
            }]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0` the `processContentExclude` option has been renamed to [noProcess](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#noprocess). Your `options` object should be:

```js
// ...
options: {
    // ...
    noProcess: [ // <-- Renamed from processContentExclude
        '**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd,ttf,otf,woff,svg}'
    ]
},
// ...
```

I also assume that somewhere else in your configuration, (although not included in the OP), you might be using the `processContent` option - hence the corruption. Note, that the `processContent` option has been renamed to [process](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#process) so you'll need to rename that too. E.g.

```
// ...
options: {
    // ...
    process: function(foo, baz) { // <-- Renamed from processContent
        // ...          
    },
    // ...    
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still it is giving the same issue, damaging the files.
Here is my updated config.
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [ {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= options.resources %>',
                        src: ['**/*.png'],
                        dest: '<%= options.targets.dist %>',
                        options: {
                            noProcess: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd}']
                        }
                    }]

Comment: You should really edit/update your question with your updated config, and not post it as a comment. Anyway, your glob patterns are incorrect in the  code posted in the comment. Try setting `src: ['*/.png']` to `src: ['**/*.png']` and also set `noProcess: ['*/.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd}']` to `noProcess: ['**/*.{png,gif,jpg,ico,psd}']` (Note the `*/.` part has been changed to `**/*.` in both examples). Also if it's only `.png` files you are copying then the `noProcess` can be configured as `noProcess: ['**/*.png']` - there's really not need to include all the other file suffixes.